# How can I find how many different words have on the linked list?

Tags: java

I have been  trying  for a while to do a method that return, number of different words occurrences on the list. And it wasn't success.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Question is unclear. You must show the contents of the list.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the words in a `Set` and at the end count the elements present in the `Set`.

**A `set`** is a data structure similar to a `List` that **doesn't allow duplicates**.

```
public int countDistinctWords(List<String> words) {
    Set<String> distinctWords = new HashSet<String>(words);
    return distinctWords.size();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Copy the linked list into a (hash) set, and look at its size:

```
System.out.println(new HashSet<>(yourLinkedList).size());
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Java 8 you could use the `Stream` Api

```
public long countDistinct(List<String> list){
    return list.stream().distinct().count();
}
```